# Why is neq-comparison inconsistent in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

A comparison of two pandas arrays does not give the same result as performing the comparison element-wise. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

floats_with_None = np.array([None,2.3,1.4])
s_None = pd.Series(floats_with_None)
(s_None != s_None)[0] # gives True
s_None[0] != s_None[0] # gives False
```

Can someone explain the cause of this?

Comment: [`pd.Series.__eq__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f935543555ddb61619f500718ea8fd33810b0c9d/pandas/core/arraylike.py#L39) --> [`pd.Series._cmp_method`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f935543555ddb61619f500718ea8fd33810b0c9d/pandas/core/series.py#L5795) --> [`pd.core.ops.comparison_op`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f935543555ddb61619f500718ea8fd33810b0c9d/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py#L290)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas treats `None` as a "missing data" marker, and [special-cases](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.3/pandas/_libs/ops.pyx#L161) it in comparisons. Like floating-point `NaN` or `pandas.NaT`, pandas will treat `None` as unequal to everything, including itself.

`None` is still just an ordinary Python object, outside of Pandas's control, though. Pandas can only special-case `None` in comparisons implemented by Pandas. When you do

```
s_None[0] != s_None[0]
```

you're using `None`'s implementation of `!=`, which is just a default implementation inherited from `object`. This default implementation of `!=` considers all objects equal to themselves.

This discrepancy is mentioned in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html):

> One has to be mindful that in Python (and NumPy), the nan's don’t compare equal, but None's do. Note that pandas/NumPy uses the fact that np.nan != np.nan, and treats None like np.nan.

although the "Note that pandas/NumPy..." part should probably just say "Note that pandas..."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I find this very error-prone and think that other languages - like R - do a much better job in handling missing-values.

Comment: @P.Jo: R is a domain-specific language, while Pandas is a library. Pandas has to deal with existing design decisions regarding `NaN` and `None` that make sense outside of its domain. R gets to design the whole language around its domain from the ground up.

Comment: Some of this might get better as the new `pandas.NA` gets more stable and gets better integrated with the rest of the library, but any change to the current `None` behavior will probably require a long deprecation period, if it happens at all.